# Can I Prevent Eclipse Fom Adding the JRE Jars to the Classpath?

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath, eclipse-classpath

I noticed that when running a Java application or unit test in Eclipse, it explicitly adds the jars of the JRE (rt.jar, etc.) to the `-classpath` argument of `java`.

**First question**: Why? This seems unnecessary, since those jars are implicitly on the bootstrap classpath anyway, right?

**Second question**: Is there a way to prevent Eclipse from doing that? I found that I can remove those jars from `-classpath` by deleting the "JRE System Library" from the "Bootstrap Entries" in the Classpath tab for a specific run configuration, but I would like to configure this for the whole project, no for every run config separately.

Comment: Never worked with Bootstrap but did you try remove the jre from window -> preferences -> installed jres ?I would assume if eclipse doesn't have any jres/jdks registered, it wouldn't add them to the libraries either?

Comment: @Basti Thanks for the suggestion, but I think this would create more problems than it would solve. :D

Comment: Not if you include the necessary libraries using some other tool like Bootstrap for example. In some of my maven-projects the parent is a pure container for the children. I usually remove the jre from it compleatly and don't run into any problems. Try it. If eclipse explodes, we know better next time :P